# Creating Animal Crossing style world rendering with Python

Tags: python, perspective

I've dabbled a bit with writing 3D rendering code in the past, although I'm interested in knowing if there is existing code (libraries) written for/with bindings to Python that might facilitate the creation of a world effect similar to [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/videogames/detail-page/B001CM0PR8.01.lg.jpg).

The world is a tile map wrapped to barrel basically with the actor in the center and objects in the horizon falling behind a threshold.

My hope here is to try and spare myself as much as I can to do with the actual perspective, rendering, culling, etc... and focus more on the game and networking logic itself.  However any advice on the subject as to what approaches might be best suited here are welcome!

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17567/how-do-they-do-the-3d-effect-in-animal-crossing